# Comparing Dates in Kendo HTML Grid Client Template

Tags: date, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, client-templates

I need to be able to properly compare two dates within the client template of a Kendo HTML Grid.  Here is what I have:

```
                @(Html.Kendo().Grid<TfInvoicesReturnModel>()
                    .Name("invoiceGrid")
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                    .Ajax()
                                    .Sort(sort => sort.Add("OrderDate").Descending())
                                    .Read(read => read.Action("Invoices_Read", "Jobs", new { JobNo = Model.JobNo, CustomerNo = Model.CustomerId }))
                                    .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
                                    .Model(model =>
                                    {
                                        model.Id(p => p.InvoiceNo);
                                    })
                                )

                .Columns(columns =>
                {

                    columns.Bound(p => p.InvoiceNo).ClientTemplate(
                         "#if(BalanceDue > 0 && DueDate < " + @CurDate + ") {# " +
                                "<span style='color:red; font-weight:bold'>#: InvoiceNo #</span>" +
                            "#} else {#" +
                                "#: InvoiceNo #" +
                            "#} #"
                        ).Title("Invoice").Width(125);  ...
```

Where @CurDate is a variable in the view:

```
String CurDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

When I run this, CurDate is correct.  But of course the comparison is not working correctly because DueDate is not in the same format.  How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by formatting your date into the needed format.

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/dateformatting
Here is how:

```
kendo.toString(new Date(DueDate), "g") // for -> 11/6/2018 12:00 AM
```

Comment: Thanks, @Carlos - that worked!  Though now I added that to a couple other columns that use .Format and the format specified is not taking effect.  Any ideas why or how I can apply it in the client template if need be?

Comment: can you please share the expected result of the format and the one you are having? Maybe sharing the new columns code.

Comment: I put the formatting of those columns in the client template instead and that worked.  Thanks!

Comment: columns.Bound(p => p.BalanceDue).ClientTemplate(
                             "#if(BalanceDue > 0 && kendo.toString(new Date(DueDate), 'MM/dd/yyyy') < '" + @CurDate + "') {# " +
                                    "<span style='color:red; font-weight:bold'>#: kendo.toString(BalanceDue, 'c') #</span>" +
                                "#} else {#" +
                                    "#: kendo.toString(BalanceDue, 'c') #" +
                                "#} #"
                            ).Title("Balance Due").Width(125).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right;" });

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options.

1) You can calculate your condition on server and pass bool variable to client, so your template will be like that:

```
"#if(DateCheck) {# " +
    "<span style='color:red; font-weight:bold'>#: InvoiceNo #</span>" +
"#} else {#" +
    "#: InvoiceNo #" +
"#} #"
```

And action "Invoices_Read":

```
...
.Select(w => new TfInvoicesReturnModel
{
    ...
    DateCheck = w.BalanceDue > 0 && w.DueDate < DateTime.Now.Date
    ...
})
...
```

2) You should convert your DateTime property to JS date with kendo.parseDate() method from [doc](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/dateparsing) to compare dates on client side, so your template will be like that:

```
"#if(BalanceDue > 0 && DueDate < kendo.parseDate(" + @CurDate + ", YOUR_FORMAT)) {# " +
    "<span style='color:red; font-weight:bold'>#: InvoiceNo #</span>" +
"#} else {#" +
    "#: InvoiceNo #" +
"#} #"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that ultimately worked:

```
                    columns.Bound(p => p.DueDate).ClientTemplate(
                         "#if(BalanceDue > 0 && new Date(DueDate) < getTodaysDate()) {# " +
                                "<span style='color:red; font-weight:bold'>#: kendo.toString(new Date(DueDate), 'MM/dd/yyyy') #</span>" +
                            "#} else {#" +
                                "#: kendo.toString(new Date(DueDate), 'MM/dd/yyyy') #" +
                            "#} #"
                        ).Title("Due Date");
```

With this being the function to get today's date in the script section:

```
function getTodaysDate()
{
    return new Date();
}
```

Comment: I tried this exact thing, removing the balance due part and substituting my own date field and it fails, but I believe that's because my field is nullable datetime rather than just datetime.